# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = an ip that's not my server

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers

my php script has $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is equals to an ip that has nothing to do with my server's ip.

Someone got an easy explanation?

(I was thinking some bot is sending a completly wrong Host header, but i don't think it can connect to a server with a wrong host header =/ )

thx

Comment: Is this a virtual server or hosted environment?  If so then the IP's most likely will not match.

Comment: A normal HTTP library wouldn't. But a bot could indeed open a socket connection to your server and include a fake `Host: 87.31.159.22` header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HTTP_HOST` is provided by the client, in the `Host:` part of the HTTP request. It can be changed arbitrarily, though I can't see why one would want to.  See [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead.  This is defined by the server itself.

Comment: Regarding the why, I get hits with the HOST *localhost* and my *sub-domains*. Hackers look for conditions based on server host to gain access to unauthorised content.

Answer (score 3):

The `Host` header has absolutely nothing to do with connecting to the web server. It is used by the web server, once connected, to route the HTTP conversation to a particular virtual host. It may be that the virtual host your script is in is the default virtual host, in which case the HTTP conversation will be routed to it provided it doesn't match any other virtual hosts.

Comment: Exactly what I was getting at when I asked if he was in a hosted environment or using a VPS.  The HTTP_HOST is always different from the IP in that case (at least on the 3 hosting accounts I currently have).